# Is there an ad network which will let me specify custom advertisement sizes?

Tags: advertising

I'm just wondering if any of you know of an ad network that provides ads in custom dimensions **chosen by the publisher**. AdSense and other popular networks have a bunch of ads with pre-defined sizes, but none of them suit my design. Before I'm forced into changing my site layout, I'd like to know if there is a custom solution.

Comment: If an ad network allowed that, how would advertisers create their ads? They'd have to know exactly which sites their ad will be published on and then create a separate ad for each site. It would be hugely inefficient and for zero gain.

Answer (score 1):

In short no! Unless your site is so niche that advertisers approach you - even then breaking conventions is hard work (I've tried!).

Take a look at the [interactive advertising Bureau's standard sizes](http://www.iab.net/iab_products_and_industry_services/1421/1443/1452), perhaps something will fit.